# using shortcut (alias) to throw files to server with scp

Tags: scp

Does anyone know how to do this? I scp to my vps a lot and I'm trying to create a shortcut.  I normally connect with "ssh username" because I have a config file setup and use keys, but what I really want to do is make some kind of short cut so I don't have to type this all the time:

```
scp filename user@domain:/home/user/
```

Does anyone know how to do this? .bashrc isn't working out.

Answer (score 2):

scp *already* uses your ssh configuration – for example, if you've configured a `Host myvps` section so that you can do `ssh myvps`, then you can also `scp file myvps:` as well. It will pick up the username, the hostname, the keys and everything.

You don't need to specify the full path to your home directory – this is already the default location (that's why it is the *home* directory). For example, if you want to dump some files directly to $HOME, then it's enough to specify `myvps:`, and if you want to access `~/src/foo` on the server, `myvps:src/foo` would be enough.

Comment: I didn't know that, and I don't think I understand. When I type 'ssh username' I connect to my remote server without trouble. But when I type 'scp filename username' to initiate an ssh transfer, I get the error "username: Not a directory". If scp uses the information in my .ssh/config file, shouldn't what I typed work?

Comment: So, I tried "scp test.txt defacto:/home/defacto/" and it just hangs. But "ssh defacto" connects right away...

Comment: I also tried it with sudo: "sudo scp test.txt defacto:/home/defacto/", but got the error "ssh: Could not resolve hostname defacto: Name or service not known". Immediately I tested the connection with "ssh defacto" and it immediately connected without error. What's going on? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You always have to specify the `:` in scp destinations. If the server was named `defacto`, then the scp destination would need to be, at minimum, `defacto:` (or of course `defacto:/home/whatever`).

Comment: If I understand correctly, that's exactly what I typed. Here is the command I sent again: "scp test.txt defacto:/home/defacto/" (How do you make the grey background in your posts like that?)

Comment: Okay. That's really weird. I can't get scp to work, but I did get caja to connect via ssh. This isn't solved, but I did find a work around. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Thanks. Got it to work.